# Why flutter package file_picker, fileType.custom didn't work for some extension

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to limit the extension type that can be picked by my user using file_picker package. I change the fileType to custom and limit the extension into CSV only. but the problem when I already got the permission and want to choose the csv it's not selectable, why this happen ? meanwhile if I change the fileType to any it will work just fine

but the problem is I have to limit the extension type, how to fix this ?

here's my code:

```
Future pickCSVFile() async{
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: false,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: [
        'csv',
      ],
    );

    // Returns List<File>
    return result!.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList();
  }
```